# PostConstruct not being called in junits

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, postconstruct

When i am testing(JUnit) this class i get NullPointerException when i call getdata method

```
private static final Map<String, Function<String, String>> REFERENCE_MAP = new HashMap<>();

@Autowired
private static classA aobj;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    REFERENCE_MAP.put("s1", (bucketName) -> {
         return aobj.getSomething1(bucketName);
    });
    REFERENCE_MAP.put("s2", (bucketName) -> {
        return aobj.getSomething2(bucketName);
    });
    REFERENCE_MAP.put("s3", (bucketName) -> {
        return aobj.getSomething3(bucketName);
    });
    REFERENCE_MAP.put("s4", (bucketName) -> {
        return aobj.getSomething4(bucketName);
    });
}
public String getdata() {
    return REFERENCE_MAP.get("s1").apply("bucketname1");
}
```

how do i solve the problem

Comment: show your test. class / method

Comment: Also are you using junit4? 5?

Comment: i am using junit5

Answer (score 3):

In test file call the initialize method before running tests

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class testClass {

    @InjectMocks
    private mainClass mainclass;

    @Mock
    private ClassA obja;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        mainclass.initialize();

    }
}
```